# React native state changes without setState

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a screen that represents a schedule which lets the user give each week a name. Once the user finishes editing all the weeks he will presses the checkmark and the app should update the backend.

I am getting a very weird bug where the first time I click the checkmark edit data gets updated (the log says "editData changed" and the ui changes) but when I print the state inside updateTheDB it has not been updated. If I try to enter edit mode again and save without making any new changes the previous changes are updated inside updateTheDB.

I thought this was a copy by reference not but value problem but I am using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify to copy so that can't be it.

The call to setState (setEditData) is inside onSavePressed which is in a modal that opens when the user tries to name a week.

Does anyone know what could have caused this?

**EDIT**

I want the to cause a render when setEditToServer is called

This is my code:

```
const Schedule = (props: IPorps) => {
    const { week_names_props, navigation } = props;
    const days = ['s', 'm', 't', 'w', 't', 's', 'w'];

    //bottom Modal
    const [active_modal, setActiveModal] = useState<MProps>(null)

    //data 
    const [serverData, setServerData] = useState<IData>({ weekNames: week_names_props, weekEvents: {} })

    //edit_mode data
    const [editData, setEditData] = useState<IData>(null)

    //other
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const [editable, setEditable] = useState<boolean>(false)

    const doTheLoadingThingy = (): void => {
        Axios.get(`api/weeks/getWeekNameByCompanyId`, {
            params: {
                company_id: 1,
            },
        }).then((response) => {
            setServerData({ ...serverData, weekNames: response.data })
            //useEffect will hide the loading and the modal
        })
            .catch(() => { setIsLoading(false); errorToast("get") })
    }

    const setEditToServer = () => {
        console.log("setEditToServer"
        setEditData({
            weekNames: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(serverData.weekNames)),
            weekEvents: {}
        })
    }}

    useEffect(() => {
        setEditToServer()
        setIsLoading(false)
    }, [serverData])


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("editData changed")
    }, [editData])

    const updateTheDB = () => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        console.log(editData)
        //send to backend
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerLeft: () => (
                <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-around", alignItems: "center", paddingHorizontal: 30 }}>
                    {editable ? (
                        <>
                            <Icon
                                name={"check"}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    updateTheDB()
                                    setEditable(false)
                                }}/>
                            <Icon
                                name={"cancel"}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    console.log("cancel")
                                    setEditToServer()
                                    setEditable(false)
                                }}/>
                        </>
                    ) : (
                            <Icon
                                name={'edit'}
                                onPress={() => setEditable(true)}/>
                        )}

                </View>
            )
        })
    }, [editable])

    return (
        <>
            {isLoading ?
                (<ActivityIndicator size="large" />) :
                (
                    <>
                        <BottomModal
                            innerComponent={active_modal ? active_modal.modal : null}
                            innerComponentProps={active_modal ? active_modal.props : null}
                            modalStyle={active_modal ? active_modal.style : null}
                            modalVisible={(active_modal != null)}
                            onClose={() => {
                                setActiveModal(null);
                            }}
                        />
                        <WeekDaysHeader />
                        {editData ? 
                        (<FlatList
                            data={editData.weekNames}
                            keyExtractor={(item) => item.week.toString()}
                            style={styles.flatListStyle}
                            // extraData={editData?editData.weekEvents:null}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => {
                                return (
                                    <Week
                                        days={days}
                                        events={editData.weekEvents[item.week.toString()]}
                                        dayComponents={ScheduleScreenDay}
                                        week_name={item.week_name ? item.week_name : null}
                                        week_number={Number(item.week)}
                                        onHeaderPressed={editable ?
                                            (week_number, week_title) => {
                                                console.log("Pressed", week_number, week_title)

                                                setActiveModal({
                                                    props: {
                                                        week_number_props: week_number,
                                                        week_title_props: week_title,
                                                        onSavePressedProps: (new_name) => {
                                                            if (new_name) {
                                                                let tmp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(editData.weekNames))
                                                                const i = tmp.findIndex((item) => item.week.toString() === week_number.toString())
                                                                tmp[i].week_name = new_name
                                                                setEditData((prev) => ({ weekNames: tmp, weekEvents: prev.weekEvents }))
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }, modal: NameWeekModalComponet,
                                                    style: styles.weekNameModalStyle
                                                });
                                            } : undefined}
                                    />
                                );
                            }}
                        />) : null}
                    </>
                )
            }
        </>)
};

export default Schedule;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought this was a copy by reference not but value problem but I am using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify) to copy so that can't be it.

Thats exactly the problem:

```
// Always true
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(['a'])) !== JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(['a']))
```

Therefore whenever `setEditToServer` is called the component will re-render, that's because React makes a shallow comparison with the previous state when deciding for render.

```
const setEditToServer = () => {
// Always re-render
        setEditData({
            weekNames: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(serverData.weekNames)),
            weekEvents: {}
        })
    }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I don't call setEditToServer after the initial render so that shouldn't be a problem and If I will call it in the future I want it to cause a render. The problem is that the value in the ui changes but when I try to look at the state that controls it (aka editData) has not changed

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerLeft: () => (
               //...
            )
        })
    }, [editable])
```

The functions inside it used the `editData` state but the useEffect didn't have it in the deps list so when the onPress was clicked it got the old state of `editData`. The solution was to add `editData` to the deps list. Like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerLeft: () => (
               //...
            )
        })
    }, [editable, editData])
```